# Packaging a sencha touch application with sencha cmd

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I've made my app and now I want to package it so I goto my application directory in terminal containing

```
/app
/app.js
/app.json
/resources
/index.html
/touch
```

I run `sencha app build package` and I run into

```
[ERR]       Please ensure this command was executed from a valid application directory
[ERR]       Unable to locate 'app.dir' config property from sencha.cfg
```

What am I doing wrong? I am in the application directory, it contains the sdk in the touch folder.

Comment: Have you checked your sencha.cfg file in the .sencha/app directory? Does it have an `app.dir` property?

Comment: What should the app.dir be? Are there any docs on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of Sencha SDK & CMD are you using? Latest version of Cmd does not work with SDK versions before 2.1.1.

Check this out : [Sencha Cmd Unable to locate 'app.dir' config property from sencha.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749050/sencha-cmd-unable-to-locate-app-dir-config-property-from-sencha-cfg)

Comment: Im using version 3.0.2.288 with the latest ST2.1 sdk available

Comment: Ill have a look at your comment you put in but you ought to give that as an answer if its correct! Honestly Sencha needs to make their stuff clearer, my experience with their sdks are all about workarounds to get functionality to actually work